# Toggling Between Two Different Views in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a search form in an Angular app that I've written. You can type in a word or phrase and when you hit search you are given the results with the option to toggle between a standard list view (formatted to look like the results in a google search) or in a card view. The list view is the default setting and the user can toggle to the card view.

I handle the toggling via a `mat-button-toggle-group` and on `(change)` of the `mat-button-toggle`, I set a boolean variable that is used by my markup to determine which view to show. This all works brilliantly if I'm switching from the default view (list) to the card view. But when I want to switch back to the list view from the card view, nothing happens. I've added logging to the `(change)` event so I know the variable is being reset but nothing is happening. Below is my code:

**search.component.html**

```
<div class="search-fields page-content">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" disabled="false">
    <mat-label>Keyword(s)</mat-label>
    <input #txtSearch matInput type="search" placeholder="Search Phrase" [(ngModel)]="this.searchPhrase" (keyup.enter)="onSearchClick()">
    <button mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="this.searchPhrase=''">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSearchClick()">Search</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="dataModel" class="container page-content">
  <div class="full-width">
    <mat-button-toggle-group value="false">
      <mat-button-toggle selected="true" value="false" (change)="onToggleClick($event.value)" matTooltip="View List">
        <mat-icon>view_list</mat-icon>
      </mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="true" (change)="onToggleClick($event.value)" matTooltip="View Tiles">
        <mat-icon>view_comfy</mat-icon>
      </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
  </div>
  <span class="query-info">Showing {{ getBeginHits() }} - {{ getEndHits() }} of {{ this.dataModel.totalHits }} results </span>
  <div *ngIf="!isTile" class="result-detail">
    <div *ngFor="let page of dataModel.pages">
      <div class="full-width">
        <h3><a href="{{ '/page/' + page.id.trim() }}">{{ page.title }}</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="full-width matches-detail">
        <span>{{ page.matchesString }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="full-width result-snippet" [innerHTML]="page.textSnippet">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <mat-grid-list cols="5" *ngIf="isTile">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let page of dataModel.pages" [colspan]="1" [rowspan]="1">
      <mat-card >
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title><strong>{{ page.title }}</strong></mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="{{ this.imageBase + page.id.trim() + '.jpg' }}" alt="Photo of page" />
        <mat-card-content>
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let s of page.matchesArray">{{ s }}</li>
          </ul>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="{{ '/page/' + page.id.trim() }}">VIEW</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
  <div class="align-center">
    <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="this.currentIndex == 1" (click)="onNavClick(this.currentIndex - 1)" >
      <mat-icon aria-label="Previous">navigate_before</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of this.getPageArray(); let i = index;">
      <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="onNavClick(i + 1)">{{ i + 1 }}</button>
    </ng-container>
    <button mat-icon-button [disabled]="this.currentIndex == this.dataModel.totalPageResults" (click)="onNavClick(this.currentIndex + 1)">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Next">navigate_next</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**search.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {PageService} from '../service/page.service';
import {PageResult} from '../../shared/models/page-result.model';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {_sanitizeHtml} from '@angular/core/src/sanitization/html_sanitizer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  searchPhrase: string;
  isTile: boolean;
  dataModel: PageResult;
  imageBase: string = environment.imageUrl + 'thumbs/';
  currentIndex: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private pageService: PageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getPageArray(): any[] {
    return new Array(this.dataModel.totalPageResults);
  }

  getBeginHits(): number {
    return ((this.dataModel.currentIndex * this.dataModel.resultLimit) - this.dataModel.resultLimit + 1);
  }

  getEndHits(): number {
    return (this.dataModel.currentIndex * this.dataModel.resultLimit);
  }

  onNavClick(index: number) {
    this.currentIndex = index;
    this.pageService.search(this.searchPhrase, index, 20)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.dataModel = data,
        error => console.log(error),
      );
  }

  onToggleClick(value: boolean) {
    this.isTile = value;
    console.log('isTile: ' + this.isTile.toString());
  }

  onSearchClick() {
    this.currentIndex = 1;
    this.isTile = false;
    this.pageService.search(this.searchPhrase, 1, 20)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.dataModel = data,
        error => console.log(error),
      );
  }

}
```

If you look at the `onToggleClick()` method, the logging there tells me that the `isTile` variable is definitely being changed. It's just not triggering a change to the variable. Furthermore, if I try to use the paging buttons, the view stays in Tile mode even if I've flipped tile mode off. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try wrapping

```
<mat-grid-list cols="5" *ngIf="isTile">

in a <div *ngIf="isTile">
```

as you do for full width ? maybe *ngIf is not working in mat-grid-list, but should work